# Yaml to CSV format

Tags: python-2.7, yaml, file-conversion, pyyaml

### I have a YAML file with multiple documents like below

-A:1

-B:2

---

-A:4

-B:5

-C:3

I want to get this in CSV format.

A,B, C

1, 2

4 ,5 ,3

I have tried using PyYAML 3.12 package but 'load_all' is giving generator as output like below

[{A:1},{B:2}]

[{A:4},{B:5},{C:3}]

I am unable to get it in CSV format. Python 2.7 is supporting only PyYAML 3.12 not 5.3 . Is there any other way to get this in CSV format?

Comment: `load_all` loads YAML into native Python types (`dict`, `list` etc). You will need a CSV implementation (e.g. the standard package `csv`) to convert it to CSV.

Comment: It gave generator in python 2.7

Comment: Yes, a generator that returns each document in the YAML file as native Python object. What's your problem with that?

Comment: I am new to python. I am unable to parse below into CSV.         [{A:1},{B:2}]

[{A:4},{B:5},{C:3}]

Comment: Okay so first, Python 2.7 is unsupported and shouldn't be used anymore. Especially if you're a newcomer, learn Python 3 instead. Second, SO is not a place that simply writes code for you. You need to show the code you already have and describe the specific problem that stops you from achieving what you want to do. Currently, you're not showing *any* code. I mentioned the standard `csv` package, did you try using it? What problems do you have with it? If you're unsure about the language's fundamentals, I suggest reading some tutorials before you ask here.